# Unable to get elements by className: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a Paginated form. I am using a code from GFG but I am unable to get the elements. Everything seems fine in the code.

HTML code:

```
<form id="agentForm" action="">

        <h1>Register:</h1>

        <div class="tab">Name:
          <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Contact Info:
          <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Birthday:
          <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Login Info:
          <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
          <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
          <span class="step"></span>
          <span class="step"></span>
          <span class="step"></span>
          <span class="step"></span>
        </div>
        
        </form>
```

JS code:

```
 var currentTab = 0
showTab(currentTab)

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('tab')
  x[n].style.display = 'block'

  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById('prevBtn').style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('prevBtn').style.display = 'inline'
  }
  if (n == x.length - 1) {
    document.getElementById('nextBtn').innerHTML = 'Submit'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('nextBtn').innerHTML = 'Next'
  }
  
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}
```

The line "x[n].style.display" shows **undefined** for x[n]. When I console.log **x** I am getting an HTMLCollection[] which is actually showing all the **tab** classes. Don't know why I am unable to manipulate the value though

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (preferable as snippet) that shows the described behavior, because your script [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/8cmqy79d/)

Comment: @Andreas my bad, I made the change. It will be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with the placement of the  tag. The script tag needed to be at the end and not the

Answer (score 0):

Hope this logic will help you.

Logic

- Start from `currentTab` as value zero.
- `showTab` function recieves the increment value +1 or decrement value -1 as param.
- I on each showTab execution, update the value of currentTab.
- Keep a node list array index, loop throgh this list and display node withic matches the currentTab. Hide rest of nodes.

```js
var currentTab = 0
showTab(currentTab)

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
  currentTab += n;
  const nodeList = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  nodeList.forEach(node => {
    if(node !== currentTab) {
      x[node].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      x[node].style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
  // x[currentTab].style.display = 'block'

  if (currentTab == 0) {
    document.getElementById('prevBtn').style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('prevBtn').style.display = 'inline'
  }
  if (currentTab == x.length - 1) {
    document.getElementById('nextBtn').innerHTML = 'Submit'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('nextBtn').innerHTML = 'Next'
  }

  // fixStepIndicator(n)
}
```

```html
<form id="agentForm" action="">

  <h1>Register:</h1>

  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="showTab(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="showTab(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: My issue is not the logic of iterating through the values of x. My issue is that x[n] or x[node] is showing undefined in spite of console.log(x) showing all the elements with 'tab' class names.

Comment: @MayukhDasgupta when was the function `showTab` got executed? Pleas provide the valiue that you passed as paramanter for `showTab` when function crashed.

Comment: With the initial value 0

Comment: @MayukhDasgupta I checked that, I cannot find any issues except the function `fixStepIndicator` is not defined. Plase check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kgu4mtdq/

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate your undefined error in JSFiddle. Here is my code (I tried changing the background color instead).

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")

// background color changes to red
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```